# Find the minimum turnover accounts

Tags: python

My client has a number of different brokerage accounts in Excel. For each account, it has an account name, account type, stock name, and the allocation for each stock. The number of stocks in each account varies. The file looks like the following:

```
Account Name  Account Type   Stock Name  Stock Allocation     
MN001         #1             ABC         40%    
MN001         #1             ABD         60%

MN002         #2             ABC         50%    
MN002         #2             ABD         40%    
MN002         #2             EFG         10%    

MN003         #3             ABC         20%    
MN003         #3             ABD         40%    
MN003         #3             EFG         40%    

MN004         #4             ABC         30%    
MN004         #4             ABD         70%
```

We want to move from the account type #1 (MN001) to other account types (either MN002, MN003, or MN004). The criteria is to find the account with the minimum turnover. For example, the turnover between MN001 and MN002 is ABC(0.1) + ABD(0.2) + EFG(0.1) = 0.4. The turnover between MN001 and MN003 is ABC (0.2) + ABD(0.2) + EFG(0.4) = 0.8. The turnover between MN001 and MN004 is ABC (0.1) + ABD(0.1)= 0.2. MN004 has the minimum turnover.

Therefore, the desired output:

```
From Account/Account Type    To Account/Account Type    Minimum TurnOver
MN001        #1              MN004      #4              0.2 

MN002        #2              MN001      #1              0.4
```

It seems very hard to do it in Excel. Could it be done in Python? Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be done in Python, and it could look something like this.

```
accounts = [{'ABC':0.4, 'ABD':0.6}, {'ABC':0.5, 'ABD':0.4, 'EFG':0.1}]
```

This are your accounts, MN001 is `accounts[0]` and MN002 is `accounts[1]` and so on..

```
def compute_turnover(first_account, second_account):
    turnover = 0

    for stock_name, stock_allocation in first_account.items():
        other_allocation = second_account.get(stock_name) 
        if other_allocation is not None:
            turnover += abs(stock_allocation - second_account[stock_name])
        else:
            turnover += stock_allocation

    for stock_name, stock_allocation in second_account.items():
        other_allocation = first_account.get(stock_name) 
        if other_allocation is None:
            turnover += stock_allocation

    return turnover
```

Define a compute_turnover function as above, you call it with MN001 and MN002 you get the expected result

```
>>> compute_turnover(accounts[0], accounts[1])
0.4
```

Now let's suppose you have a `list1` with the accounts that need to be transferred and a `list2` with the target accounts. You can just need to convert the two lists in python dictionaries and then iterate as follows

```
list1 = [{'ABC':0.4, 'ABD':0.6}, {'ABC':0.5, 'ABD':0.4, 'EFG':0.1}]
list2 = [{'ABC':0.4, 'ABD':0.6}, {'ABC':0.5, 'ABD':0.4, 'EFG':0.1}]

turnover_accounts = []
for account in list1:
    min_turnover = 1e9
    turnover_account = None

    for target_account in list2:
        if compute_turnover(account, target_account) < min_turnover:
            min_turnover = compute_turnover(account, target_account)
            turnover_account = target_account

    turnover_accounts.append(turnover_account)
```

Your `turnover_accounts` list will have the index of the target accounts with minimum turnover.

Comment: Hi Alessandro Solbiati, thank you very much. I am a python beginner and trying to learn as much as I can. I have two lists of accounts. One is the list of accounts to be converted (#1 list). And the other list is the list of target type accounts (#2 list). Both lists have the same data format as in the question above. We need to go through the #1 list (more than 1000) and find the minimum turn over account in #2 for each account in #1 list. Can you please advise the code on how this iteration could be done? I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Edited and added iteration as requested

Comment: It depends on how your data is formatted, if you are using .csv files you can use thel library 'pandas' and use pandas.read_csv(). If you liked my answer you can upvote on the left and put it as correct answer

Comment: to put it to a dictionary, it depends on your csv. You should look online "pandas dataframe to dict" and see what fits you best

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189312/discussion-between-alessandro-solbiati-and-steve-p).